# Sparse coding and matching pursuit algorithms

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, np-hardness, approximation-algorithms, sparse-matrix

- Is it true that all known sparse coding algorithms which work efficiently in practice don't have convergence proofs and always use an intermediate step of a matching/subspace pursuit algorithm on the current dictionary? And that this step of using a pursuit algorithm intermediate to solve a compressed sensing problem on the intermediate dictionaries is what is the hard part which is analytically intractable?
- Or is there any hardness result known for either matching pursuit algorithms or sparse coding?
- I understand that there are sparse coding algorithms with proofs like, arXiv:1206.5882 (full rank dictionary), arXiv:1309.1952, arXiv:1310.7991, arXiv:1503.00778, arXiv:1407.1543 but I would like to understand why these aren't the ones that is probably ever used in practice.

---

It would be helpful if you could kindly add in other references that you might know of for either provable sparse coding or matching pursuit algorithms.